# This is the first time I have done VERSUS I am doing it for

Tags: meaning-in-context

**The classic construction is "This is the first time I have done something"**

What about this? Is this also valid?

> 1 - You are reading a Bible, aren't you? Do you like it?
>
> - I don't know yet. I am reading it for the first time only.
>
> 2 - Do you recognize me? I am your cousin.
>
> - Sorry, but I am seeing you for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no mistake in using "for the first time" in a sentence "doing something for the first time".

In the first sentence the placement of "only" is rather odd.  "Only" tends to creep forward: "I'm only reading it for the first time".

In the second example, the verb "see" is not usually used in continuous form. And so the whole sentence is rather odd.  In that particular context you would use a different verb and a completely different way to express yourself "I'm sorry, I don't think we've met." for example.

Comment: This is written by a native speaker "Not the most flattering introduction to this word, which I am here seeing for the first time." "Failure is simply the opportunity to begin again, this time more intelligently."

Comment: I hope I was clear.  "see" is not normally used in continuous form, but it may be used in some special situations and contexts, or for a particular effect.  "... which I am seeing for the first time" is deliberately "odd", to give a sense of being "in the moment"  It doesn't work in all or even in most contexts, and it doesn't work in your example.

Comment: I don't see the relevance of the quote about failure.

Comment: I mistakenly posted another sentence, I meant this one "Assembled there, the people fasten their eyes on the coming boat as they would on a wonder they are seeing for the first time."

Comment: Again, that is highly "marked" language.  It is an historical present tense narrative, and this is done to create that sense of immediacy.  But that is not needed and not idiomatic iif you say "I'm seeing you for the first time" in a plain and literal sense.  Now if you mean in an almost magical way...  "Kate, when you took off your glasses, it's like I'm seeing you for the first time. I've never realised how beautiful you are!"    So my answer stands  "Normally, don't use "seeing" in present continuous""